# matrix addition - Multiple unique identifiers

Tags: r, matrix

AM trying to add elements from two different matrices, Each of the matrix has got three unique identifiers as below:

Matrix A:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1   x    1   2   10 11 12 13 10

2   y    1   2   11 12  14 12 13 

3  y    1   3  12  10 11  12
```

The second matrix look like:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1   x    1   2   20 14 17 10 10

2   y    1   2   11 12  14 12  13 

3  y    1   3  17  10 19  12
```

Please note that the variables A, B, and D form unique identifiers for each of the participants.
I would wish to write a code so that as I sum the matrix values I consider this.

Comment: Those look more like dataframes than matrices.  Are they character matrices, or dataframes?  Is there really a good reason to keep them as matrices?  I think `plyr` would be useful for this but tends to work with data frames.

Answer (score 1):

You should your data in the long format.

```
library(reshape2)
dat.l <- melt(dat,id=c('A','B','D'))
dat1.l <- melt(dat1,id=c('A','B','D'))
```

Then you just sum `value` :

```
dat.l$value = dat.l$value + dat1.l$value
```

Comment: Ooh, I like that (`melt`).